# SQL SELECT Statement with Multiple Parts

Tags: sql-server

I'm really struggling with something with this question. I've got the first 3 parts done.

I DON'T WANT THE ANSWER, I just need to be nudged into the right direction.

Here is the Question:

1)  The first column should provide me all of the category names (column called Category Name)

2)  The second column should provide me with the total discounted price for all products sold (do not

worry about tax or shipping) in each category (column called Total Order Value)

3)  The third column should provide me with the date of the latest order in each category (column

called Latest Orders). These dates should be pulled from a group of the last 5 orders that were created.

4)  Create a fourth column called Category Type that places the Basses and Guitars into the ‘String’

Category Type and the remaining instrument(s) in the ‘Other’ Category Type

Organize the result by the Total Order Value from largest to

Here is what I have so far:

```
   USE MyGuitarShop
   SELECT CategoryName, SUM(DiscountTotal) AS TotalDiscount, MAX(OrderDate) AS NewestOrder
   FROM Categories AS C JOIN Products AS P ON C.CategoryID = P.CategoryID
   JOIN OrderItems AS OI ON P.ProductID = OI.ProductID
   JOIN Orders AS O ON O.OrderID = OI.OrderID
   GROUP BY CategoryName
```

Here is how the Tables are set up:

```
    Categories:
    CategoryID
    CategoryName


    Products:
    ProductID
    CategoryID
    ProductCode
    ProductName
    Description
    ListPrice
    DiscountPercent
    DiscountAmount
    DiscountPrice
    DateAdded


    Orders:
    OrderID
    CustomerID
    OrderDate
    ShipAmount
    TaxAmount
    ShipDate
    ShipAddressID
    CardType
    CardNumber
    CardExpires
    BillingAddressID
```

Answer (score 0):

If CategoryType is derived from CategoryName then in the select clause part add:

```
CASE WHEN CategoryName = 'Guitar' OR CategoryName = 'Bass' 
  THEN 'String' 
  ELSE 'Other' 
END AS CategoryType
```

You will have to add the above to the GROUP BY part as well as follows:

```
CASE WHEN CategoryName = 'Guitar' OR CategoryName = 'Bass' 
  THEN 'String' 
  ELSE 'Other' 
END
```

You will have to explain how to calculate "Total Order Value" before I can do the "ORDER BY".

Comment: The OP just wanted a nudge :)

Comment: Hmmm..you're right, I gave him an almighty shove I suppose.

Comment: Lol Thanks @JohnS and @chrisb! I appreciat the help. I totally had spaced out and forgot all about using the CASE WHEN function!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you just need a nudge for (4)... Take a look at [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).  Good luck.